# ejb-jar.xml env-entry enums

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, java-ee-6, ejb-jar.xml

This is my ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ejb-jar xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         version = "3.0" 
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">

    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>EmailEjb</ejb-name>
            <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name>java:app/env/smtp.host</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>smtp.mandrillapp.com</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
            <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name>java:app/env/smtp.port</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.Integer</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>587</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
            <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name>java:app/env/smtp.transportStrategy</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>org.codemonkey.simplejavamail.TransportStrategy</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>SMTP_TLS</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
            <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name>java:app/env/smtp.username</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>user@example.com</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
            <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name>java:app/env/smtp.password</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>foobar</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Upon deployment, I get this exception:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 85; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml in archive [localgp-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT].  cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'org.codemonkey.simplejavamail.TransportStrategy' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Byte, java.lang.Character, java.lang.String, java.lang.Short, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Long, java.lang.Float, java.lang.Double]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.

That seems to suggest that, despite [the documentation](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/env_entry/env_entry.html), enums aren't allowed. Or is something else happening that I could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans 7.2.1 (latest version right now) generates an ejb-jar.xml for version 3.0 of the EJB spec which doesn't recognize enums as `env-entry-type`s. Changing it to version 3.1 resolves the issue and the resources are injected correctly.

```
<ejb-jar xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         version = "3.1" 
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">

    <!-- Stuff goes here. -->

</ejb-jar>
```